# show stateprovider template with ng-view

Tags: angularjs

How can i include the view in `<ng view></ng-view>`, i will have multiple template, so i cant just include one using `ng-include src=""`
It shows content only in different link, but not using `ng-view`

```
 <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#/inventory/list">list view</a></li>
    </ul>
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

My stateprovider

```
app.config(function config( $stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('inventory',{
    url:'/inventory',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inventory/main.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Inventory' }
  }
  ).state('add',{
    url:'/inventory/list',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inventory/list.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'List field' }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS standard `$route` and `$routeProvider` is incompatible with `ui-router` `$state` and `$stateProvider`.

Use `ui-view` and also go though `ui-router` docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki